# Filter ids when a maximum score is not observed in r

Tags: r, filter

I need to filter `id`s that do not have `maximum score` points in them. Here is my sample dataset looks like

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3,3, 4,4,4,4,4, 5,5,5),
              score = c(0,1,2,0,1, 1,0,1,1, 0,1,2,3,3, 3,1,2,0,3, 0,1,0),
          max.score = c(2,2,2,2,2, 1,1,1,1, 4,4,4,4,4, 3,3,3,3,3, 2,2,2))

> df
   id score max.score
1   1     0         2
2   1     1         2
3   1     2         2
4   1     0         2
5   1     1         2
6   2     1         1
7   2     0         1
8   2     1         1
9   2     1         1
10  3     0         4
11  3     1         4
12  3     2         4
13  3     3         4
14  3     3         4
15  4     3         3
16  4     1         3
17  4     2         3
18  4     0         3
19  4     3         3
20  5     0         2
21  5     1         2
22  5     0         2
```

In this dataframe, I need to filter `id`s `c(3,5)` because these `id`s do not have the `max.score` in them. The desired output would be:

```
> df
  id score max.score
1  3     0         4
2  3     1         4
3  3     2         4
4  3     3         4
5  3     3         4
6  5     0         2
7  5     1         2
8  5     0         2
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Try `df %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(!any(score %in% max.score[1])) %>% ungroup`

Comment: As `max.score` is constant by group you can use `filter(!(max.score %in% score))` on the grouped data.